# modify syslog-ng.conf to add limit of log file size and log rotate option

Tags: syslog, syslog-ng

### I have modified /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf file to create my own log file at different location using below changes :

```
source s_src {
       system();
       internal();
};

 destination d_syslog { file("/home/abc/test_log"); };

log{ source(s_src); destination(d_syslog); };
```

---

what should i do to limit this file size to 1MB , and once it reaches 1MB it should be converted to test_log.0 and new logs should be in test_log ?

Thanks in Advance , 
Asit .

Answer (score 0):

currently you cannot limit the size of logfiles in syslog-ng.
You can either

- use date-macros in your filenames to rotate logfiles for example daily, (for example,  file("/var/log/remote/${HOST}/${YEAR}*${MONTH}*${DAY}.log" create-dirs(yes));   ), or
- you can use logrotate (see https://www.balabit.com/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/example-logrotate.html )

Comment: is there any other alternative option to do such ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know of any